# macOS llvm compilation : ld: library not found for -lomp

Tags: c, macos, gcc, g++

I have to use openMP for a project with my university. To do that I downloaded llvm using brew and I replaced cc = gcc in the makefile by `CC=/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang`.

Now it seemed like it was going to work, but I get an unexpected error `ld: library not found for -lomp clang-11: error: linker command failed with exit code 1`.

When I run `llvm-config --system-libs`  I get : `-lm -lz -lcurses -lxml2`.

I'm a complete beginner on this subject, but I think I have to install the ld library ?
Can anyone help ?

edit: full makefile

```
C=/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang
CFLAGS = -O2 -fopenmp
LDFLAGS = -fopenmp

EXEC =  bubble.run  \
    mergesort.run   \
    odd-even.run

HEADER_FILES = $(wildcard *.h)

RAND_INIT=0

ifeq ($(RAND_INIT), 1)
$(Initialization of the vector is random)
CONFIG_FLAGS += -DRINIT
endif

all: $(EXEC)

%.run: %.o utils.o
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^

%.o: %.c $(HEADER_FILES)
    $(CC) -c $(CONFIG_FLAGS) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

clean:
    rm -f $(EXEC) *.o *~

.PHONY: clean
```

Comment: What is the full compiler/linker command(s)? Please _edit_ your question and post your Makefile in a code block here.

Comment: Under `fedora` [linux], `libomp.so` is part of the `libomp` package as "OpenMP runtime for clang". So, you'll have to install the macOS equivalent. Note that _real_ `gcc` has all openmp stuff built in [IIRC]. Try looking in `/usr/local/lib*` for the library. You may just need to add a `-L` option if the file already exists.

Comment: I might run the compiler under `strace` to see what files it tries to access (e.g. when looking for `libomp*`). I saw a reference that says macos doesn't have `strace` but does have `truss` or `dtruss` to do the same thing. Also, I might do: `find /usr/local -xdev -name '*omp*'` [maybe under `/` as well] to see if the lib already exists in a non-standard place

Comment: @CraigEstey I do have libomp installed with brew. Not sure what I'm supposed to do with though, or what the thing with -L does.

Comment: If you installed libomp, you need to know the full path of the `.so` file. That's what the `find` command I mentioned can tell you. See `man ld` for info on `-L`. So, if the full path were: `/usr/local/lib64/libomp.so`, then you'd want: `LDFLAGS += -L /usr/local/lib64`

Comment: I understand. I can't seem to find the `libomp.so`, all I have are `.rb`, `.a` and `.dylib`. I tried copying `libomp.a` and `libomp.dylib` in `llvm/lib` and put the right `.h` in `llvm/include` but it doesn't seem to work (still missing linked ld).
(Your search command returns nothing for `libomp.so`.)

Comment: If you looked closely at the actual `find` command I gave, it _will_ find the variants. It _may_ be a solution, but, if it were me, I would _not_ pollute standard directories with addons. If the libomp package wanted the files in (e.g.) `/lib`, it would have installed them there.

Comment: yeah my "solution" doesn't even work. The exact command you gave returns thousands  of files so i tried to narrow it down by replacing `*omg*` with `*libomp*` or `*omp*.so` but there's nothing relevant. I feel like I tried everything I could with the info I have.

Comment: Well, you said you tried copying `libomp*` into `llvm/lib`!?!? So, from which directory did you copy it _from_?

Comment: From `/usr/local/opt/libomp`. I copied the content of `/usr/local/opt/libomp/lib` into `.../llvm/lib` and same with the `include` directory.

Comment: So, did you try: `LDFLAGS += -L /usr/local/opt/libomp/lib` and `CFLAGS += -I/usr/local/opt/libomp/include`? Again, what about using `strace` equiv `truss/dtruss`?

Comment: oh my god I was editing the wring make file, it worked with LDFLAGS and CFLAGS, thanks a ton !

Comment: `s/wring/wrong/` :-) Have a coffee! You probably need a rest!

Comment: Haha I will, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved in the comments by Craig Estey.
So here's my *tutorial* for compiling openMP on macOS.

1. install llvm with `brew install llvm`
2. install libomp with `brew install libomp`

Now, it `clang` and `clang++` are calling llvm compilation, OpenMP should compile. But that's where I ran into the issue of missing ld linked.

3. use `find /usr/local -xdev -name '*libomp*'` to find where libomp is installed, probably at `/usr/local/opt/libomp`

Now when you compile/in your makefile, use clang instead of cc/gcc and add `LDFLAGS += -L <YOUR PATH TO LIBOMP>/libomp/lib` and `CFLAGS += -I/usr/local/opt/libomp/include` to your make file. Compiling should now work.